# How to add Array with hint and hint_string?

Tags: godot, gdscript

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71150959/18005234) answer it is possible to create export variables via `_get_property_list()` like this:

```
var _properties := {
    "x": "",
    "y": ""
}

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    if not Engine.editor_hint or not is_inside_tree():
        return []

    var result := []
    for property_name in _properties.keys():
        result.append(
            {
                name = property_name,
                type = typeof(_properties[property_name]),
                usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT
            }
        )

    return result
...
```

but what if I wanted to add an array with hint and hint_string?
the equivalent of `export(Array,float,0, 100,10) var Multiples=[0,0,0,0]`

```
result.append(
{
  name = property_name,
  type = typeof(Array),
  usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
  hint=???,
  hint_string=???
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Scroll to the end where it says "To put it all together" if you just want the rules.**

---

To begin with, I'll be using code that looks like this:

```
tool
extends Node

var backing_field

func _set(property:String, value) -> bool:
    if property == "property_name":
        backing_field = value
        return true

    return false

func _get(property:String):
    if property == "property_name":
        return backing_field

    return null
```

Pretend that code is always there. So we will be specifying this property `"property_name"` in `_get_property_list`.

---

For reference, I'll start by showing how `_get_property_list` works in other cases. For example we can make the property an `int`:

```
func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_INT,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
        }
    ]
```

And we can use `hint` and `hint_string` to further specify how it will behave in the inspector panel. For instance we can narrow the property to an specific range like this:

```
func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_INT,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_RANGE,
            hint_string = "0,10"
        }
    ]
```

And that would give the property a range from `0` to `10`.

---

We can of course specify that the property is an `Array` instead of an `int`:

```
func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_ARRAY,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
        }
    ]
```

And here is where we get to the question: What `hint` and `hint_string` can we use with `TYPE_ARRAY`.

If we have a look at [GDScript exports](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html#exporting-arrays) we find out that we can export an array and also specify the type of the elements, like this:

```
export(Array, int) var my_array = [1, 2, 3]
```

So, presumably we will be able to do that with `_get_property_list` instead (Without resourcing to `Pool*Array` types - we will not be able to specify ranges with those anyway). How do we do that? *I'll show you.*

---

**From here on, these is all undocumented.** *Most of this I figured this out by experimentation. By the way, for Godot 4.0 this will be different.*

To specify the type of the elements of the array:

- The `hint` must be `26` in Godot 3.5. This is an undocumented constant I found by experimentation, and I
  found the name in Godot source: `PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING`, however
  it is not exposed to GDScript. These are the values for other versions of Godot:

  - Godot 3.0: `PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING = 23`
  - Godot 3.1 to 3.4: `PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING = 24`
  - Godot 3.5: `PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING = 26`

  To avoid the issue, I'll declare it as `PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2`.
- The `hint_string` must be the `TYPE_*` constant converted to `String` with `":"` appended at the end.

For example, if the type of the elements is `int`, you put `"2:"` in the `hint_string`. If the type of the elements is `float`, you put `"3:"` on the `hint_string`. Like this:

```
const PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING := PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_ARRAY,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING,
            hint_string = str(TYPE_INT) + ":"
        }
    ]
```

*For reference `str(TYPE_INT)` is `"2"`, so `str(TYPE_INT) + ":"` is `"2:"`.*

Ok, but what if we want to specify more about the elements? For example what if we want to say that we have an `Array` of `int` in the range from `0` to `10` using `_get_property_list`?

In that case the `hint_string` will be:

- The the `TYPE_*` constant converted to `String`
- Followed by `"/"`
- Followed by the `PROPERTY_HINT_*` constant converted to `String`
- Followed by `":"`
- Followed by the `hint_string` you would use with that `PROPERTY_HINT_*` constant.

Like this:

```
const PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING := PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_ARRAY,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING,
            hint_string = str(TYPE_INT) + "/" + str(PROPERTY_HINT_RANGE) + ":0,10"
        }
    ]
```

*Here the `hint_string` comes up as `"2/1:0,10"`. Notice that the `"2"` is now followed by `"/"` instead of `":"`.*

---

Alright, that begs the question. What if the elements of the `Array` must also be `Array`s? Well, we can go back to having an `Array` and specifying the type, like this:

```
const PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING := PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_ARRAY,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING,
            hint_string = str(TYPE_ARRAY) + ":"
        }
    ]
```

*Here the `hint_string` comes up as `"19:`. That the `"19"` came from `str(TYPE_ARRAY)`, and I'm highlighting that because I'll start using writing `"19"` instead of `str(TYPE_ARRAY)` in the code.*

Well, Let us say we want to specify the type of the elements of the arrays that are elements of the array. For example, let us say that we want an array of arrays of int. That would be like this:

```
const PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING := PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_ARRAY,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING,
            hint_string = "19:" + str(TYPE_INT) + ":"
        }
    ]
```

*Here the `hint_string` comes up as `"19:2:`.*

And we can put more `"19:"` to make an `Array` of `Array`s of `Array`s of whatever and so on. So this is an `Array` of `Array`s of `Array`s of `int`s:

```
const PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING := PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_ARRAY,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING,
            hint_string = "19:19:" + str(TYPE_INT) + ":"
        }
    ]
```

*Here the `hint_string` comes up as `"19:19:2:`.*

---

Now, let us say that you want to `int` in the range from `0` to `1` as before, we would have to do this:

```
const PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING := PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "property_name",
            type = TYPE_ARRAY,
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_DEFAULT,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING,
            hint_string = "19:19:" + str(TYPE_INT) + "/" + str(PROPERTY_HINT_RANGE) + ":0,10"
        }
    ]
```

*Here the `hint_string` comes up as `"19:19:2/1:0,10`.*

Notice (again) that we don't have `"19:19:" + str(TYPE_INT)` followed by `":"` but by `"/"`.

---

**To put it all together**:

- The `type` must be `TYPE_ARRAY` (Which is `19`).
- The `hint` must be `26` for Godot 3.5 (this is an undocumented constant called `PROPERTY_HINT_TYPE_STRING`, historically it has been `PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2`).
- The `hint_string` must be:

  - `"19:"` for each level of nested `Array`s we want. *None if the `Array` is not meant to have other `Array`s inside.*
  - Followed by the `TYPE_*` constant that represents the type of the elements.
  - Then by either:

    - To specify what would be the `hint_string` for the elements:

      - `"/"`
      - Followed by the `PROPERTY_HINT_*` constant converted to `String`
      - Followed by `":"`
      - Followed by the `hint_string` you would use with that `PROPERTY_HINT_*` constant.
    - Otherwise:

      - `":"`

*The other attributes are not affected by this being an array. You can set them as if you were making a property of the type of the elements of the array.*

---

These are some examples of GDScript exports translated to `hint_string` (remember to set `type` to `TYPE_ARRAY` and `hint` to `26` for Godot 3.5, or use `PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS + 2` for any Godot 3.x up to and including 3.5):

- `export(Array)`: `""`
- `export(Array, int)`: `"2:"`
- `export(Array, Array, int)`: `"19:2:"`
- `export(Array, int, 0, 10)`: `"2/1:0,10"`
- `export(Array, Array, int, 0, 10)`: `"19:2/1:0,10"`
- `export(Array, int, "Red", "Green", "Blue")`: `"2/3:Red,Green,Blue"`
- `export(Array, Array, int, "Red", "Green", "Blue")`: `"19:2/3:Red,Green,Blue"`
- `export(Array, float)`: `"3:"`
- `export(Array, Array, float)`: `"19:3:"`
- `export(Array, float, 0, 100, 10)`: `"3/1:0,100,10"`
- `export(Array, Array, float, 0, 100, 10)`: `"19:3/1:0,100,10"`
- `export(Array, Texture)`: `"17/17:Texture"`
- `export(Array, Array, Texture)`: `"19:17/17:Texture"`

---

*What kind of experimentation I did to find this out? I exported some variables and had a look at what was reported by `get_property_list`, and then tried different combinations in `_get_property_list` to see what worked and what didn't, what was necessary and what wasn't. Then I looked at Godot source code as sanity check.*

*By the way, the last documented `hint` constant `PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS` with value `21` in Godot 3.0, `22` in Godot 3.2 to Godot 3.4, and value `24` in Godot 3.5. But there are values beyond it, see [the source code](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/core/object.h#L58).*

Comment: In Godot 3.5, `PROPERTY_HINT_IMAGE_COMPRESS_LOSSLESS = 24`