# Export Struct-like objects for arrays

Tags: arrays, object, godot, gdscript

I have been bashing my head about this and can't seem to figure it out. In another engine, I could make a struct, then make an array of that struct that I could then edit in the inspector. There seems to be no way of doing this that I can find in Godot.

I want to have a Resource that holds the starting Value and Type of multiple faces on a dice. For example, one side could have "2 Damage" while another has "Heal 3." (this is a first-time godot experiment inspired by [Slice&Dice](https://tann.itch.io/slice-dice)). Every tutorial I watch however makes it seem like, if I want to do so, I'd have to make a completely new Resource for each combination of Value and Type (Damage 1 Resource, Damage 2 Resource, etc.)

```
class_name DiceResource extends Resource

class DiceFaceData:
    export var BaseValue = 0
    export(Resource) var Type = preload("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/Damage.tres")
    func _init():
        Type = 2
        BaseValue = preload("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/Damage.tres")

export(Array) var Faces = [DiceFaceData.new()]
```

I cannot get DiceFaceData to show up in the Inspector's array, or be on the list of object types for an array. Extending Object doesn't work. Extending Node means I have to instantiate it, which I don't want to do for an editor-only Resource.

I find it hard to imagine Godot doesn't have anything like this available. Is there anything I can load in the inspector as just data and not have to instantiate it? Another option is create two arrays, one with int and another Resource, but that seems inconvenient to fill out. Or should I just give up with Resources and make everything a Node attached to a Node attached to a Node? Thanks!

Godot version 3.4.3

EDIT: If you're someone coming from Unity or Unreal, what you're looking for is Resource. While compared to ScriptableObjects or DataAssets from those other engines, that's not the complete answer. You would think, because of the way those game engines handle it, you can only create custom SO or DA as assets in the filesystem/content browser, **but you can also use Resources as instanced classes**. Instead of creating a new Resource in the filesystem, you can use

```
export(Resource) var n = preload("res://MyResourceScript.gd").new()
```

In the inspector, you can choose from the list **New MyResourceScript** and create it. You won't be referencing an externally made Reference file, you'll be creating a custom one right there. And look at the below answer as well on good tips for using Resources in cool ways.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I want to say that I sympathize. Custom resources and the inspector do not work well. There is a solution on the work… However that does not mean that the only thing we can do is keep Waiting For Godot.

---

### Observations on your code

About your code, I want to point out that `DiceFaceData` is not a resource type. You could write it like this:

```
class DiceFaceData extends Resource:
    export var BaseValue = 0
    export(Resource) var Type = preload("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/Damage.tres")
    func _init():
        Type = 2
        BaseValue = preload("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/Damage.tres")
```

And… That solves nothing.

And, also, by the way, I remind you can put it on its own file:

```
class_name DiceFaceData
extends Resource:

export var BaseValue = 0
export(Resource) var Type = preload("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/Damage.tres")
func _init():
    Type = 2
    BaseValue = preload("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/Damage.tres")
```

And… That is not the solution either.

---

Something else I want to point out is that GDScript has types. See [Static typing in GDScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html). Use them. To illustrate…

This is a Variant with an `ìnt` value

```
var BaseValue = 0
```

This is an `int`, typed explicitly:

```
var BaseValue:int = 0
```

And this is an `int`, typed implicitly with type inference:

```
var BaseValue := 0
```

And if you were using types Godot would tell you that this is an error:

```
BaseValue = preload("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/Damage.tres")
```

Because `BaseValue` is an `int`, and you setting a resource to it.

---

### The Array of Resources problem

First of all, this is a `Variant` that happens to have an `Array` value, and it is exported as an `Array`:

```
export(Array) var Faces = []
```

Let us type it as an `Array`:

```
export(Array) var Faces := []
```

And sadly we cannot specify the type of the elements of the arrays in Godot 3.x (we need Godot 4.0 for that feature). However we can specify how we export it.

So, this is an `Array` exported as an `Array` of `Resource`:

```
export(Array, Resource) var Faces := []
```

*See [Exporting arrays](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html#exporting-arrays).*

Before you could not get your custom resource type to show up. And now you have the opposite problem: all the resource types show up. *And this includes your custom resource type, if it in its own file.*

You would guess that we need to specify the resource type we want:

```
export(Array, DiceFaceData) var Faces = []
```

And that would be correct if it were a build-in resource type. But it is a custom one. *We are expecting this to be fixed in a future version.* Meanwhile we will have to leave it with `export(Array, Resource)`.

---

### Mitigating the problem with an addon

To alleviate the pain of having all the possible resource types, consider using the addon "Improved resource picker" by MakovWait. You can find it on [itch](https://makovwait.itch.io/imrpoved-resource-picker-for-godot), or on [github](https://github.com/MakovWait/improved_resource_picker).

---

### A proper solution

Anyway, we can do better. But you are going to need to make your script a [`tool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/running_code_in_the_editor.html?highlight=tool) script (you do that by putting `tool` on the top of the script, and it means that the code from the script can and will run on the editor).

We are going to define a setter with [`setget`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#setters-getters), and in there we are going to make sure the elements are of the correct type:

```
export(Array, Resource) var Faces = [] setget set_faces

func set_faces(new_value:Array) -> void:
    Faces = []
    for element in new_value:
        element = element as DiceFaceData
        if element == null:
            element = DiceFaceData.new()

        Faces.append(element)
```

Now, in the inspector panel when you increase the size of the array, Godot will insert a new null element to the array, which makes the setter we defined run, which will find that null and convert it to a new instance of your custom resource type, so you don't have to pick the resource type in the inspector panel at all.

---

### A "hacky" solution

As you know, this does not work:

```
export(Array, DiceFaceData) var Faces = []
```

However, we can replace an `export` with [`_get_property_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-property-list). What happens is that Godot asks the object what properties it has to show up in the inspector panel. Godot does this by calling [`get_property_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#get_property_list) And it will statically report the ones it found while parsing (the ones with export). However, Godot also defines a function `_get_property_list` where we can add more at run time.

*See also [Advanced exports](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html#advanced-exports).*

Which begs the question, could we possibly make it work with `_get_property_list`? Kind of. The The code like this:

```
var Faces := []

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "Faces",
            type = TYPE_ARRAY,
            hint = 24,
            hint_string = "17/17:DiceFaceData"
        }
    ]
```

It will show up on the inspector as an array where the elements can only be of your custom resource type.

The issue is that it causes some error spam. Which you might or might not be OK with. It is your project, so it is up to you.

I know it looks like voodoo magic in part because we are using some undocumented stuff. If you want an explanation of that `24` and that `17/17:` see [How to add Array with hint and hint_string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71175772/402022).

---

### About the sub-resources

> Every tutorial I watch however makes it seem like, if I want to do so, I'd have to make a completely new Resource for each combination of Value and Type (Damage 1 Resource, Damage 2 Resource, etc.)

I'm not sure what you are getting to with "a completely new Resource", but yes. A resource is an instance of a resource type. And each of those combination would be a resource.

Perhaps "Damage", "Heal" and so on are resources too. Let us see… I'm guessing that is what the `Type` is for:

```
export(Resource) var Type = preload("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/Damage.tres")
```

Godot would be showing all the resource types it is aware of, which is a pain. I'm going to suggest a different approach than those above for this: Make an `String` enumeration.

```
export(String, "Damage", "Heal") var Type:String
```

That will show up as a drop down list on the inspector panel, with the options you specified.

Why `String` and not `int`? Ah, because you can then do this if you so desire:

```
var type_resource := load("Resources/DiceFaceTypes/" + Type + ".tres")
```

*I'm assuming that those have the code that actually does damage or heal or whatever.*

---

Alright, but when you add a new type of dice face, you would have to come here and update it… Or do you? With the power of `tool` scripts we are going to update that list to reflect the files that actually exist!

First of all, we are not going to use `export`, so it will be just:

```
var Type:String
```

And now we can export it from `_get_property_list`. There we can query the files. But before we do that, so we are clear what we have to do, the following code is equivalent to the export we had before:

```
func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            name = "Type",
            type = TYPE_STRING,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_ENUM,
            hint_string = "Damage,Heal"
        }
    ]
```

*No undocumented stuff here.*

Our task is to build that `hint_string` with the names of the files. And that looks like this:

```
const path := "res://"

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    var hint_string := ""
    var directory := Directory.new()
    if OK != directory.open(path) or OK != directory.list_dir_begin(true):
        push_error("Unable to read path: " + path)
        return []

    var file_name := directory.get_next()
    while file_name != "":
        if not directory.current_is_dir() and file_name.get_extension() == "tres":
            if hint_string != "":
                hint_string += ","

            hint_string += file_name

        file_name = directory.get_next()

    directory.list_dir_end()
    return [
        {
            name = "Type",
            type = TYPE_STRING,
            hint = PROPERTY_HINT_ENUM,
            hint_string = hint_string
        }
    ]
```

*Ah, yes, set the `path` constant to the path of the folder where the resources types you have are.*

---

### Addendum post edit

I want to elaborate on this example:

```
export(Resource) var n = preload("res://MyResourceScript.gd").new()
```

Here we are exporting a variable `n` as a `Resource`, which will appear in the Inspector panel. The variable is currently a Variant, we could type it `Resource`:

```
export(Resource) var n:Resource = preload("res://MyResourceScript.gd").new()
```

And then we don't need to tell Godot to export it as a `Resource`, because it is a `Resource`:

```
export var n:Resource = preload("res://MyResourceScript.gd").new()
```

---

Something else we can do is `preload` into a `const`. *To be clear, `preload`s are resolved at parse time.* Like this:

```
const MyResourceScript := preload("res://MyResourceScript.gd")

export var n:Resource = MyResourceScript.new()
```

This way, if you need to use the same script in multiple places, you don't need to repeat the path.

---

However, you might not need the path at all. If in the script `res://MyResourceScript.gd` we add a `class_name` (at the top of the script):

```
class_name MyResourceScript
```

Then we don't need to use `preload` at all. That name will be available everywhere, and you can just use it:

```
export var n:Resource = MyResourceScript.new()
```

---

**Where is that resource stored?**

Potentially nowhere. Above we are telling Godot to create a new one when our it initializes our object (e.g. which could be a `Node`, or another `Resource` - because, yes, `Resource`s can have `Resource`s) and those would only exist in RAM.

However, if you modify the `Resource` from the Inspector panel, Godot needs to store those changes somewhere. Now, if you are editing a Node, by default they go to the scene file. If you are editing another `Resource`, then it goes to wherever that `Resource` is stored. *To be clear, scenes are resources too (`PackedScene`). And, yes, that means a file can have multiple `Resource`s (A main resurce and sub-resources).* You could also tell Godot to store the `Resource` in its own file from the Inspector panel. The advantage of giving a file to a `Resource` is in reusing it in multiple places (multiple scenes, for example).

So, a `Resource` could be stored in a file, or not stored at all. And a resource file could have a `Resource` alone, or it could also have sub-resources as well.

---

*I'll take a moment to remind you that scenes can have instances of other scenes inside. So, there is no line between scenes and the so called "prefabs" in Godot.*

---

**… Did you know?**

You can save the resources you created in runtime, using `ResourceSaver`. Which could be a way to save player progress, for example. You can also load them using `load` or `ResourceLoader` (in fact, `load` is a shorthand for `ResourceLoader.load`).

In fact, if you can use `load` or `preload` on something, it is a `Resource`. Wait a minute, we did this above:

```
const MyResourceScript := preload("res://MyResourceScript.gd")
```

Yep. The `Script` is a `Resource`. And yes, you can create that kind of resources in runtime too. Create a `GDScript` object (`GDScript.new()`), set its `source_code`, and `reload` it. Then you can attach it to an `Object` (e.g. a `Node`) with `set_script`. *You can now start thinking of meta-programming, or modding support.*

Comment: This is very informative, but I think a bit off track. While _get_property_list() is good to know, (thank you for that), it still ignores combining it with an int (and possibly more values down the line)

Comment: In C# i could say
`struct DiceFaceStruct{ String Type; int Value; }`
Then the Resource **DiceResource** would have an **array of DiceFaceStruct**. 

DiceResource would be a unique dice per character class. So fighter lv1 would have a DiceResource with a "1 Damage" side, a paladin lv20 would have a "20 Damage" side. This side would be one element of the array of DiceFaceStructs. I don't want to create a unique resource for Damage 1-20, I want a resource for just Damage, and a struct that combines that with a value.

Comment: @DemonBismuth structs in C# are value types. Among Godot types, the reference types inherit form `Reference`. If you don't want a `Resource` and you don't want a `Reference`, you would inherit from `Object`. However if you do that, then the Inspector panel won't be able to handle them. I really don't know what the issue with creating resources is. If you look at the "proper solution", it is creating the resources with `DiceFaceData.new()` and then you edit them. Perhaps if you explain the concern with resources, or the workflow you want I can improve the answer.

Comment: @DemonBismuth It might be worth noting that Godot lacks tuple types. I suppose that if everything else fails, you can follow the alternative approach you mention on the question (creating multiple arrays). You have seen how to use `setget` with a `tool` script to react to changes to the array from the inspector which you can use to make sure they are the same size. See also `notify_property_changed`. I suppose another option is an `EditorPlugin` that extends the functionality of the Inspector panel, but I don't know if it is worth it.

Comment: My understanding of Resources was that I had to create them in the content directory as separate files. They were compared to ScriptableObjects in Unity. Are you saying I could create Resources that exist solely inside the array without a separate "file" for it? I also don't know about Reference types. There seems to be a little bit of writing on it, but I don't see many examples of how it is used. especially unhelpful when the word "reference" is practically unsearchable in this context

Comment: Oh my god. I just tried the preload().new() for a resource and it works. I'm sorry for not understanding before, my conception of how these things work is skewed by my time in Unity and Unreal. The idea that Resource could both be an Asset in the content folder OR a unique variable type was just not possible for me to conceptualize coming from more rigid game engines.

Comment: @DemonBismuth Yes, a resource can exist without being serialized. A resource can be serialized to its own file, or to the file of another resource , if it is a sub-resource of it. If you can load or preload something, it is a resource. Thus, scenes are resources, and so are scripts. Now, a resource is an instance of a resource type, which you can define in a script. So if you load a script, it is a resource, and might also be a resource type, from which you create resources. Finally, usually scenes have multiple sub-resources. By the way, an scene is just a serialized node (and dependencies).

Comment: @DemonBismuth So, Godot Object is not reference counted, nor serializable. The Reference and Resource classes add those functionalities, respectively. Funny enough, a Node is neither. So, you packed Nodes in PackedScenes which are Resources, and you save or load those. Once loaded, you get he Nodes back with the instance method. And yes, the same PackedScene would have as sub-resources whatever the Nodes need, including exported variables and so on, so they don't need their own files. Saving them to their own files allow you to share them between multiple scenes.