# Check if an object is of a class given the class name in string?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Let's say I have an object and I'm given a class name in string
How do I check if the object is of that class?

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    var given_class_name="KinematicBody2D"
    if($Obj is given_class_name):
       ...
```

Comment: I also found [this](https://godotengine.org/qa/24745/how-to-check-type-of-a-custom-class)

Comment: The methods [`get_type`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/2.1/classes/class_object.html#class-object-get-type) and [`is_type`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/2.1/classes/class_object.html#class-object-is-type) are part of Godot 2. By the way, they just changed `godotengine.org/qa` to `ask.godotengine.org`, this is the fixed link: [How to check type of a custom Class?](https://ask.godotengine.org/24745/how-to-check-type-of-a-custom-class).

Comment: @Theraot I meant the answer involving `if my_object is preload("custom_class.gd"):` but thank you for fixing the link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`get_class()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_object.html?highlight=Object#class-object-method-get-class) to find the class of an `Object`, ignoring `Script`s. Which in this case should be sufficient:

```
var given_class_name="KinematicBody2D"
prints($Obj.get_class() == given_class_name)
```

---

But that is not every case, is it? Perhaps you want to check a base class, then this does not work:

```
var given_class_name="PhysicsBody2D"
prints($Obj.get_class() == given_class_name)
```

Instead we can use `is_class`:

```
var given_class_name="PhysicsBody2D"
prints($Obj.is_class(given_class_name))
```

Or we can ask `ClassDB`:

```
var given_class_name="PhysicsBody2D"
var obj_class := $Obj.get_class()
prints(
    obj_class == given_class_name
    or ClassDB.is_parent_class(given_class_name, obj_class)
)
```

---

But what about `Script` classes?

Perhaps you remember that we can find the class name of a script by looking at `_global_script_classes`, something like this:

```
var obj_class_name := $Obj.get_class()
var script:Script = $Obj.get_script()
if script != null:
    obj_class_name = script.resource_path
    for x in ProjectSettings.get_setting("_global_script_classes"):
        if str(x["path"]) == script.resource_path:
            script_class_name = str(x["class"])
```

The above code will set `obj_class_name` to either:

- The class name of the script of `$Obj`, if it has any.
- The path of the script of `$Obj`, if it has any.
- The build-in class of of `$Obj`.

However, since we want to check if it is of a given type that is not sufficient. Since we also need to check `Script` inheritance. As it turn out it is more convenient to figure out what kind of class is the name we are given and work from there:

```
func is_instance_of(obj:Object, given_class_name:String) -> bool:
    if ClassDB.class_exists(given_class_name):
        # We have a build in class
        return obj.is_class(given_class_name)
    else:
        # We don't have a build in class
        # It must be a Script class
        # Try to find the Script
        var class_script:Script
        for x in ProjectSettings.get_setting("_global_script_classes"):
            if str(x["class"]) == obj_class_name:
                class_script = load(str(x["path"]))
                break

        if class_script == null:
            # Unknown class
            return false

        # Get the script of the object and try to match it
        var check_script := obj.get_script()
        while check_script != null:
            if check_script == class_script:
                return true

            check_script = check_script.get_base_script()

        # Match not found
        return false
```

---

We are almost there. As you know, in GDScript you can extend using a script path (see [Classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#classes)). So we might consider resource paths of script valid class names... We can support that too:

```
func is_instance_of(obj:Object, given_class_name:String) -> bool:
    if ClassDB.class_exists(given_class_name):
        # We have a build in class
        return obj.is_class(given_class_name)
    else:
        # We don't have a build in class
        # It must be a script class
        var class_script:Script
        # Assume it is a script path and try to load it
        if ResourceLoader.exists(given_class_name):
            class_script = load(given_class_name) as Script

        if class_script == null:
            # Assume it is a class name and try to find it
            for x in ProjectSettings.get_setting("_global_script_classes"):
                if str(x["class"]) == obj_class_name:
                    class_script = load(str(x["path"]))
                    break

        if class_script == null:
            # Unknown class
            return false

        # Get the script of the object and try to match it
        var check_script := obj.get_script()
        while check_script != null:
            if check_script == class_script:
                return true

            check_script = check_script.get_base_script()

        # Match not found
        return false
```

---

*You could go the extra mile and support a Variant instead of an `Object`. Then you can check its type with `typeof`... If it is `TYPE_OBJECT` then you proceed to check for a class. If it isn't, you would need a giant switch to check the names of build it types (similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71150959/402022), but with the type names).*

---

For anybody trying to do this in GODOT 4: `ProjectSettings.get_setting("_global_script_classes")` does not work anymore. Instead use `ProjectSettings.get_global_class_list()`.

Comment: How does the [is keyword](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#inheritance) compare to this answer? The docs say it can be used "to check inheritance". Does it do less than your code? Edit: Ah wait, the difference is that turning a string into the target class is the hard part, right?

Comment: @lucidbrot Yes. This answer is for the case where you only have a `String` that has the name of the class. Which would be the case when you only get it in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there were some errors with @Theraot's completed function. I've tested functionality in 4.2.1

```
static func is_instance_of_string(obj : Object, given_class_name : String) -> bool:
    if ClassDB.class_exists(given_class_name):
        # We have a build in class
        return obj.is_class(given_class_name)
    else:
        # We don't have a build in class
        # It must be a script class
        var class_script : Script
        # Assume it is a script path and try to load it
        if ResourceLoader.exists(given_class_name):
            class_script = load(given_class_name) as Script
            
        if class_script == null:
            # Assume it is a class name and try to find it
            for x in ProjectSettings.get_global_class_list():
                
                if str(x["class"]) == given_class_name:
                    class_script = load(str(x["path"]))
                    break
                
        if class_script == null:
            # Unknown class
            return false
        
        # Get the script of the object and try to match it
        var check_script : Script = obj.get_script()
        while check_script != null:
            if check_script == class_script:
                return true
            
            check_script = check_script.get_base_script()
        
        # Match not found
        return false
```